# log4cplus truncates file despite configured to append

Tags: log4cplus

log4cplus is truncating a file when reopening it, despite me using a properties file with `Append=True`. What should the entries be to get this to append and not truncate?

Here are the entries from my properties file:

```
log4cplus.appender.TRACE=log4cplus::FileAppender
log4cplus.appender.TRACE.File=c:\test.log
log4cplus.appender.TRACE.layout=log4cplus::PatternLayout
log4cplus.appender.TRACE.ImmediateFlush=true
log4cplus.appender.TRACE.Append=true
log4cplus.appender.TRACE.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{%H:%M:%S.%q} %t %-25.25c{1} %m%n
```

Using log4cplus 1.1.2 RC1 on Windows OS.

I should add this is a multi-threaded application where I am not seeing the append. 
I tried using an AsyncAppender instead of File Appender , but it caused a crash in the application.

Comment: What version of log4cplus are you using?

Comment: This should not happen. The only situation where it could happen is on file IO failure, when log4cplus tries to reopen the file in `FileAppender::reopen()`. This is because there appears to be a known bug in MSVC C++ library that forces truncation of files if the file open mode is only `std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::ate` (no `std::ios_base::app`). I can try to reproduce it maybe tomorrow when I get have access to a Windows box.

Comment: Thanks - let me know if you need more information . I have a multi-tiered application, the dll that uses log4cplus is loaded by the application and  perhaps unloaded and reloaded again , which maybe why the truncation is happening. ( the application itself is a black-box to me but the dll that is loads log4cplus and used by the application is under my control)

Comment: It happens to me in Kubuntu using gcc 9.3.0